# calculate the index of a array element reference

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

Is it possible to calculate the index of a referenced scalar from an array?

in C you can use pointer arithmetic to retrieve the index.

```
SomeType array[500];
const SomeType* e = &array[42];

// [...]

size_t index = e-array;
```

Is there some similar way in Perl?

```
my @array = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
my $e = \$array[4];

# [...]

my $index = '???';
```

The reason:

I have a relatively large (> 6Mio entries) Array with equally structured geometrically related data.

I also have some kind of priority based queue that contains references to this array. while processing this queue new elements are added and the queue has to be resorted. Since this queue also will grow quite large. and the priorities of the elements changes and are derived from the array element and its neighbors, i would like to avoid complex entries in the queue (memory size and allocation performance) and have only the reference their to directly access the information from the array.

But it seems that using indexes in the task-list would be the best option.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Can you please explain in more detail exactly what you're trying to do? Usually it's a bad idea to do "direct translation" of C to Perl.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot it is not a direct translation but I thought that this would help describing what i want. one possibility to solve my problem would be to keep (index, value)-Objects, but i thought using the references would be nicer, since the list, that would keep this objects will be modified (insert, sort, remove) very often and will grow quite large, as well as the source `array`

Comment: The question here is *why* you need to do this. After you assign something from the array to a separate scalar, why do you need to know the index? If you're attempting to do things like this, you probably want a hash instead. Again, you need to clarify the purpose of needing to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why not roll your own type with such a feature? (You can even `tie` it so that `=` acts like you want it to.) What you want is very, very specific. Even if there were possible to do that directly, it may just be clearer to have a simple little class.

Answer (score 0):

[List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) provides routines such as:

- `first_index`
- `last_index`
- `bsearch_index`
- `indexes`

etc. Depending on the circumstances, using one of these may be more efficient than just using plain old `grep`:

```
my @i = grep $array[$_] == $v, 0 .. $#array;
```

Comment: searching through the array is no option. because performance is important and the array is quite large. I was looking for a way to *calculate* the index. similar to C.

Comment: Perl is not C ... References are not pointers. Also, how would you get a pointer to a particular element in C if you did not already know it?

Answer (score -1):

$e contains a reference, and you can compare references for equality.

```
my @array = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
my $e = \$array[4];
#..
my $index =$#array;
$index-- while ($e ne \$array[$index] && $index >=0);

print $index;
```

prints out 4.